# AngularJS Compatibility with browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am facing a Problem in AngularJS Compatibility, Does there are any feature that is not supported by Google Chrome?
Actually we make the AngularUI Calendar, And for that we use JSFiddle Link

```
http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/xqjtw/52/
```

,Actually this UI calendar is supported on FireFox but not on GoogleChrome, this error is come

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/master/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js
```

Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. (index):1
Uncaught Error: No module: ui

What to do?

Comment: I seriously doubt that Angular.js, created by Google, would be incompatible with Google Chrome; And I personally have never seen any issues.  However, you are describing a 3rd party module, which certainly could have some issues.  Although, a 404 error seems to be a different issue entirely.

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180007.  This is an issue with Github, not with the browser.  It is possible that some browsers may not enforce the MIME change, and appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to load resource` has nothing to do with AngularJS not being compatible with Chrome. Given the fact, that AngularJS is developed by Google.

Coming to your problem of 404, when I visited this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/master/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js ,
the page there says `Not Found`. 
Check the script `src`, and modify it accordingly to load correct js file.

Comment: Do you open that link in Chorme and Firefox , The Calendar is shown in FireFox , but the same Link in Chorme gives an error in Console

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox displays `Not Found`.
Chrome console  error : `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Firefox console error : `The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.`

Answer (score 0):

Digging in to the error just a bit, and this is what I found on the [Github blog](https://github.com/blog/1482-):

> We added the  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff  header to our raw URL responses way back in 2011 as a first step in combating hotlinking. This has the effect of forcing the browser to treat content in accordance with the  Content-Type  header. That means that when we set  Content-Type: text/plain  for raw views of files, the browser will refuse to treat that file as JavaScript or CSS.

Basically, the Raw view (which you are trying to use) is not a CDN, it is a feature to make browsing the code on Github easier for humans.  It was never intended to be used for web pages to link to the raw file view.  the MIME change is a step in preventing this sort of action.

In essence, you should either link to an official CDN of a script you intend to use, or include the script as a part of your project; never link to Raw Github data.